# What to check first when buying second hand iPhone 4S?

Tags: iphone, macos

I am going to choose and buy second hand iPhone 4S (GSM).

I have owned and repaired few 3GS but none of 4S. I need few suggestions what to check with this particular model from people with experience of owning or repairing those. I have pentalobe screwdriver and I am confident with opening it and checking inside if you suggest. I am not really experienced with schematics though.

If you feel like providing with general recommendadion on how to make sure if it is not locked to Apple ID and such, please do. It is also appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check if the WiFi is working properly. The WiFi chip often fries on iPhones 4S

Comment: Thanks, Édouard, for mentioning this. Did you repair those? I know there is a reflowing recommended for them. I wonder if it is a sure thing. If it is I might opt for broken wi-fi one if price is cheap enough.

Answer (score 0):

Check the IMEI number to make sure it is not blacklisted/blocked in your country.

Comment: How can a user do that before it is their phone (and also after)

Comment: Ask the seller for the IMEI Number which is located on the phone box or under Settings in the iPhone and you can use this free website to check- http://www.iphoneox.com

Comment: Who owns this and where is it shown it is not a scam to get IMEI numbers, there is no legal contact information which would be a legal requirement in EU